# Why "Hello" > "World" is returning false

Tags: javascript

Can anyone explain me why this:

```
"Hello" > "World"
```

is returning false?

Comment: You're going to have to at least explain what language you're using.  That said, there's a good chance that it's sorting alphanumerically.

Comment: sorry my bad..JavaScript

Comment: Can you explain why you expect it to return `true`?

Comment: Because `H` is not greater than `W` - it's the same reason the string "0999" is less than the string "2".

Comment: ah now it makes sense. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It compares them char by char, first it compares "H" > "W" and since that's `false`. It returns `false`.